# Custom Scrollbar Style: iOS

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to style the scrollbar in iOS with React Native's `ScrollView` component?

Looking through the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html) there is no option for doing this. However it is possible to style the scrollbar, with webkit, inside of a `WebView` component.

I'm looking to style something similar to this image.

[image]